# Java Azure Functions deployment fails with timeout issue

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

When deploying Azure function using the maven plugin `mvn azure-functions:deploy`, a lot of the times I receive the below error. Usually it just works retrying a few times.

> [INFO] Trying to deploy artifact to CodeRuntimePrac3... [WARNING]
> [bbc8d6e1-1, L:/10.28.17.70:64315 -
> R:coderuntimeprac3.scm.azurewebsites.net/20.40.202.19:443] The
> connection observed an error java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
> Channel response timed out after 60000 milliseconds. at
> com.azure.core.http.netty.implementation.ResponseTimeoutHandler.responseTimedOut
> (ResponseTimeoutHandler.java:58) at
> com.azure.core.http.netty.implementation.ResponseTimeoutHandler.lambda$handlerAdded$0
> (ResponseTimeoutHandler.java:45) at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask (PromiseTask.java:98) at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run
> (ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute
> (AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks
> (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:500) at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run
> (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run
> (ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run
> (FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) at java.lang.Thread.run
> (Thread.java:748) [INFO] Successfully deployed the artifact to
> https://coderuntimeprac3.azurewebsites.net [INFO] Deployment done, you
> may access your resource through coderuntimeprac3.azurewebsites.net
> [INFO] Syncing triggers and fetching function information [INFO]
> Querying triggers...

This is ad-hoc. It works a few times and failes other times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below configuration in `pom.xml` for me.

```
    <deploymentType>RUN_FROM_BLOB</deploymentType>
```

You need to include it inside `configuration` tab.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-deployment-type

Now the app deployment always succeeds.